# Clarification about the little x

Tags: notation, accidentals

[image]I read through many comments and think I generally understand the idea of a little x. So I am now seeing one in a piece of music (More, Quincy Jones, transcribed by Boris Myagkov, for alto sax) which has a little x before a G (which is already sharped in the key signature), so my understanding is I just play an A.

The issue is the next note is just an A, which shouldn't be sharped according to the key signature. Doesn't make any sense to me, which makes me wonder if I'm misunderstanding. Why would they have me play a double-sharp G and then an A?

Comment: My best guess would be for key reasons (E.g. a chord C E xG, verses C E A, being a first inversion). I’d put an answer if I knew the music, but I don’t.

Comment: A slight possibility of playing that note using two different fingerings - but without seeing the dots, it's impossible to answer this as it stands.

Comment: updated with a screenshot--I wanted to include initially but didn't know how, so thanks for pushing me to figure it out! It's the 2nd bar of the music.

Comment: This must be the recording from which the transcription was made: https://open.spotify.com/track/0a545c4gOsyYupVvliDOy0?si=2c362b64dbf349a9

Comment: I think the G double sharp should be notated as A. the C double sharp as D, etc. The error probably comes from the first voice using raised notes outside the scale, but not this voice.

Comment: @Jos If the G double sharp should be an A then what should the A be?  The chord changes, so playing the same note twice doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

This is simply a copyist's writing error. Possibly bar 2 should be the same as bars 6, 10 and 14, i.e. one tone lower. As written, it makes no sense.

Comment: so I wasn't crazy. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've edited the question with the part, it seems that the copyist accidentally wrote the second measure a step too high (but wrote the accidentals as they should be).  In other words, the part should have an F double sharp and a G sharp.  Since the G sharp is present in the key signature, there is no accidental.  The same notes appear in measure 6.

---

Original answer:

If you're talking about the arrangement shown at https://www.scribd.com/document/115478441/Music-Score-Big-Band-More then I suspect you've misidentified the note, or perhaps you are working from a hand copy or a different edition in which the notes were written incorrectly.

In the second alto sax part there are several F double sharps followed by G sharp (the first is in the second measure) and several C double sharps followed by D sharp (the first is in the fourth measure), but I do not see G double sharp anywhere.  I scanned the chart and the parts several times, but I didn't read them closely, so there may be a G double sharp that I have overlooked.  If so, please let me know in a comment and I will revise the answer accordingly.

Comment: Commenting is only possible from 50 XP. Unless there's an exception for answers to one's own question or something.

Comment: @Divizna new users can always comment on their own questions and on answers to those questions.

Comment: Good to know. (And no idea where I'd find that info, it's not included in [Privileges](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).)

Comment: @Divizna but the privilege is called "comment everywhere" and is described as "leave comments on other people's posts."  More detail is given at https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment: "you can _always_ comment on your own posts, and any part of your questions."

Comment: The question has been updated and looks like m. 2 is different in the OP's source vs this scribd one, probably reinforcing Aaron's guess of copyist's error.